# how to identify Google App Engine app from browser string?

Tags: google-app-engine

Some app is hitting my site excessively from GAE.  Here is the browser string in the logs:

```
AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine; appid: ware)
```

Can that app be identified ?   "appid" would seem to indicate this but it doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Are you sure it's not http://ware.appspot.com/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The appid part of the user agent specifies the app's unique ID - the app in question is thus 'ware.appspot.com'. App Engine developers cannot change that part of the user-agent string.